# Rails form passing false as default value for boolean while submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox, boolean

I want to submit false as a default value for rails form while submitting it.

But however after submitting i am getting null as a default value.

The code is below

```
<%= f.check_box :known, {}, "false" %>
```

The column name is **known** for the table name **notes**

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: If you *always* want `false` as the default value, you should consider setting it as the default value in the database. You could do this with a migration, e.g. `change_column :notes, :known, :boolean, default: false`.

Comment: Try `<%= f.check_box :known, {}, "false", "true" %>`

Comment: Hey Jon, i did that. Here is the migration code. add_column :notes, :known, :binary, default:false. After migrating the the value submitted is strange. Instead of false i am getting x'66616c7365' . I don't know why..

Comment: Hey @Jon that works. I am getting an entry of **f** as default value in DB.

Comment: But @pavan, i want to do something like yours to change the value on submission. But can you please explain how your code works?

Comment: Is my suggestion worked?

Comment: @pavan Gve me a minute. I will try.

Comment: @Pavan .Tried but the default entry is false as you can see in the screenshot. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5zllolssgjjob9a/Screenshot%202015-07-05%2012.28.46.png)

Comment: Is that what you wanted right?

Comment: @Pavan No. For the **create** action i want it to be false. For **edit** action  i want to give the user an option to change it to true or false using checkbox.

Comment: Then you should go with the suggestion by @Jon and just give it as `<%= f.check_box :known %>`

Comment: Thanks @Pavan. But i think i did't stated my problem well. For the **create** action using migration **default: false** works. For the edit action    **<%= f.check_box :known %>** is not updating the db with **true** for **known** column.

Comment: U ter @Jon. A little help is needed.

Comment: Sorry. Instead give `<%= f.check_box :known, {}, "true", "false" %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82396/discussion-between-pavan-and-praveen-kj).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by **@Jon**, If you ***always*** want `false` as the ***default*** value, you should set it as the default value in the database. The below migration code does that.

```
change_column :notes, :known, :boolean, default: false
```

And if you want to give the user an option to change it to ***true***, then specify the `check_box` like below.

```
<%= f.check_box :known, {}, "true", "false" %>
```